# What is $\int\sin (x^2)\,\mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Can anyone help me to solve this integral problem:

$$\int \sin (x^2)\,\mathrm dx$$

I have tried every method that I know, but still can't get any completion.

Comment: It is the non-elementary [Fresnel Integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral) $S(x)$

Comment: In other words, when there's no simple form, name it!

Comment: My **blind guess**, based solely on the idea that $\int e^{(x^2)}dx$ is know to be non-elementary is that this problem is also non-elementary.